# Rails Form for frontend with no model logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am working on a Rails App, for which the model logic is not in the frontend, and it retreives data from the backend API.

I was referring to the form helpers guide , and **in Section 2.2 Binding a Form to an Object** , it explains about the binding of form to model object so new and edit form can be a single page by binding the form elements to model object.

```
articles_controller.rb:


def new
  @article = Article.new
end
```

The corresponding view using form_for looks like this

```
articles/new.html.erb:


<% form_for :article, @article, :url => { :action => "create" }, :html => {:class => "nifty_form"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_area :body, :size => "60x12" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/form_helpers.html

While in my code, I get the values via API call as a JSON object.

```
def view_request

    @request_type = "View"

    id = params["id"]
    rest_resource = RestClient::Resource.new( ENV['TEST_API'] + "/" + id, :verify_ssl => false )
    request = rest_resource.get :Authorization => cookies.signed[:remember_token], :content_type => 'application/json'
    @response = JSON.parse(request)
    render " request"
end
```

What would be the best way to create forms for both new and edit in this scenario ?

Comment: Did you end up sorting this out?

Comment: Yes, your answer helped. Thanks!

Comment: Super! Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to check out [form_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag). Then inside that form, you'll use `tag` variants, like `text_field_tag`.

You'll have to do a little extra work to get your one form to manage both new and edit, but it's not too bad.

BTW, in an effort to fully decouple my views from my models, I exclusively use `form_tag` and never access models or model instances in my views. It's a little nuts, but it helps me protect views from changes in my models.